# How do I save a nested model, and then see that nested model's key's, and values as JSON with Mongoose, MongoDB, and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm saving an account schema, and nesting it in a User schema with Mongoose, MongoDB, and Node. 
Save works fine, but when I look at the saved object JSON, I only see the objectId for the nested schema, and not it's keys, and values. 
How can I save the nested schema, so that when I look at the User obj, I see the 
all the nested schema object's keys, and values?

```
[
  {
    "account": [
      "5ac6ed27ed8b4bcbdcfa572b"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2018-04-06T03:44:39.388Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-06T03:44:39.388Z",
    "_id": "5ac6ed27ed8b4bcbdcfa572d",
    "userId": "test20@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
 [
  {
    "account": [
      "key": "value",
    ],
    "createdAt": "2018-04-06T03:44:39.388Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-06T03:44:39.388Z",
    "_id": "5ac6ed27ed8b4bcbdcfa572d",
    "userId": "test20@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: you need to query with `$lookup` aggregation. alternatively look at `populate()`

Comment: could you provide any more details? I'd like to have the key values available when I look at the JSON sent back from the save.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%24lookup+mongodb&oq=%24lookup+mongo&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.13444j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8           https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=WfHGWtWkO4GMvQTs9prQBQ&q=mongoose+populate&oq=mongoose+populate&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.25577.29048.0.29589.17.12.0.4.4.0.454.1701.0j4j2j0j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.11.1723...35i39k1j0i67k1j0i46i67k1j46i67k1j0i131i67k1j0i20i263k1.0.J60cE4Sc8fU

Comment: I'd prefer to have it available without performing an additional query of any kind. Can you expose the nested schema, instead of seeing the objectId in the returned JSON from the save?

Comment: show your schema as well... have you given the `ref` account to `user` schema... because giving `ref` makes easier to populate

Comment: Thank you Ashish. I have yes. I'm under a tight deadline, so i've opted to have the nested schema on the top level for now, but would like to know how to return JSON that shows all your data.

Comment: If your account field is an array, you'll not have any key in response of your query, if you want key / value pair, set your account field as an Object's Array